# Check if some edge crosses some minimal cut

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, graph-algorithm

I am struggling with the following question (and solution actually):

> Given `G(V,E)`, a flow-network (capacities are integers), We denote the maximum-flow by `f*`. Check for an edge `e` if:
>    1. It crosses some minimal-cut.
>    2. It crosses every minimal-cut.

The solution suggests:

1. Decrease the capacity of the edge `e` by `1` and check if the new maximum flow equals `f*-1`. return true if so.
2. Increase the capacity of the edge `e` by `1` and return true iff the max-flow increased.

I'd be glad if you could explain to me what's the idea behind this algorithm.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem):

> the max-flow min-cut theorem states that in a flow network, the maximum amount of flow passing from the source to the sink is equal to the total weight of the edges in the minimum cut, i.e. the smallest total weight of the edges which if removed would disconnect the source from the sink.

1. If `e` does cross a min-cut it means that it is one of a group of edges (let's call it `c_group`) that:

   A) if removed from the graph, the source and the sink will not be connected anymore (have no path between them)

   and B) the sum of their weights (let's call it `c_sum`) is minimal (there is no group of edges that satisfies (A) and has a smaller sum).

   When we reduce `e`'s weight by 1, from (A) we know `c_group` is a cut, and from (B) we now that `c_sum` was the minimal value of a cut (sum of its edges' weights) in the graph and now `c_group`'s value is of course `c_sum-1` because `e` is in `c_group` and we reduced its weight by `1`. so we know that `c_sum-1` is the new minimal cut value in the graph (even if `e` belongs to other cuts, it can only appear once in a cut so its weight's reduction means every cut it belongs to got reduced by `1`, so the minimal cut value cannot drop more than by `1`). from the max-flow min-cut theorem we know that the new min-cut value means that the new max-flow value is the same (`c_sum-1`).

   On the other hand, if `e` does not cross a min-cut then every cut it does cross is not minimal, meaning the groups' weights' sum is larger than the minimal cut's value. As we have only integer valued weights that means they are all larger by at least `1` than the minimal value, so when we decrease `e` by `1` every cut it crosses will be reduces to the minimal value of cuts before the change or to higher value, meaning the minimal value was not changed by the reduction, and by the max-flow min-cut theorem that means the max-flow was not changed.

   So now we know that if we reduce `e`'s value by `1`, we can check the max-flow value and if it changed (got reduced by `1`) that must mean that `e` did cross a min-cut.
2. I'll go into less detail here, but if you still struggle comment and I'll expand it as well:

   When we increase `e`'s value (here it doesn't matter by how much) it changes the minimal value of a cut in the graph iff it is part of every min-cut in the graph. It is obvious that it increases the sum of every group it belongs to, and also that if there is a group of edges that constitutes a min-cut (conditions (A)+(B) in (1)) that `e` does not belong to then increasing its weight would not change that group's weights' sum and thus would not change the minimal value of a cut in the graph. From the max-flow min-cut theorem it follows that the maximum flow in the graph increases iff `e` was part of every min-cut in the graph.

*NOTE: I'm a bit alternating in my language in this answer between considering the group of edges as the cut and considering the cut as the imaginary line the edges cross. This confusion comes from the incompatible language of the quoted problem in the question and the quoted theorem that begins my answer. I'm sorry if it confuses anyone. Basically a "cut" refers to them both throughout this answer.*